# Rossolimo attack resources

Tags: 1.e4, repertoire

I am in the middle of crafting my chess repertoire from scratch and have saved up quite a bit of money for the past 3 years and I want to buy resources that are most dynamic against a particular black response.

Against the Nc6 Sicilians I want to play the rossolimo and am looking for some resources that  allow me to play this line dynamically.

Comment: So... you want to play the Bishop's opening against 1.e4 e5 and now are looking for recommendations to the Sicilian, French, Caro-Kann etc? I assume you have played against these openings before. What did you like to play and what you not like to play? It all depends on your personal preferences. A better question might be: I like to play the Closed Sicilian against 1.e4 c5, what are good resources for this opening? As you asked the question now, it is too broad and too opinion based.

Comment: OK, noted will make the required changes

Comment: If you trully want a dynamic approach go for the open sicilian. Otherwise also consider 1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. b4?!, which is quite interesting if a bit unsound (IM Andras recently published a youtube video about this variation). Rossolimo has a lot of coverage on chesspublishing, but google also found book Rossolimo and Friends by GM Kornev, though I didn't read it, so I cannot vouch for its quality. To be frank, I think it would be better for you at your stage to focus more on tactics than on openings.

Answer (score 1):

As you probably know, chessable contains an enormous amount of courses. To find the best fit to your need (here adding the Rossolimo to your repertoir) I would go as follows:

1. Go to [chessable](https://chessable.com/) > Tools > Opening Explorer.
2. Insert your position of interest and hit "Search courses for Position":[image: Rossolimo]
3. A list of the available courses that include this position will appear: [image]

In your case, make sure that it is a repertoir from White perspective. I would go for "Keep It Simple: 1. e4 - 2.0". Here is what the cover of the course says about the Sicilian:

> ♚ Take Black’s tactics out of the Sicilian. With the Rossolimo and Moscow variations with an early Bb5, you’ll disrupt Black’s usual tricks and set up a dominating center…or an endgame Black will hate you for